# Passing c# values from controller to view javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to pass values of latitude and longitude from list in controller to view script (google map). The purpose of this code is to create multiple markers on the google map based on the list of latitude and longitude from controller.

How to actually pass list from controller to view script for google map?

Here are a bit of my code:

index.cshtml

```
<script> 
@foreach (float list in ViewBag.latitude_list){
@foreach (float list2 in ViewBag.longitude_list){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(@list, @list2),
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

controller.cs

```
//add latitude and longitude to list                        
latitude_list.Add(entity.vehicle.position.latitude);
longitude_list.Add(entity.vehicle.position.longitude);

ViewData["latitude_list"] = latitude_list;
ViewData["longitude_list"] = longitude_list;
return View();
```

I am still so new to this, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is how I fill javascript google map lat and lng with C# values.
with models,

homecontroller.cs

```
latLngList.Add(new LatLng() {Lat = entity.vehicle.position.latitude, Lng = entity.vehicle.position.longitude})
```

and

index.cshtml

```
<script>
var markersArray = [];

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.latLngList){
       <text>
             markersArray.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                 draggable: true,
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng('@item.Lat', '@item.Lng', false),
                 title: 'Whatever title',
                 map: map
             }));
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly you should be using a model.

Comment: you could just do an ajax call to a controller action and pass values back and forth using JSON that maps directly to a c# model.

Comment: You have a model containing properties `double Longitude` and `double Latitude` and you pass a collection of that model to the view and convert it to a javascript array using `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly the answer would be:

- You could create a model with two properties Lat and Lng.
- Then you create a list of positions you want to pass to the view.
- I think the code should be something like this.

> LatLng.cs

```
public class LatLng
{
public float Lat {get;set;}
public float Lng {get;set;
}
```

> controller.cs

```
//add latitude and longitude to list
public class Controller
{
List<LatLng> latLngList = new List<LatLng>();
latLngList.Add(new {entity.vehicle.position.latitude, 
entity.vehicle.position.longitude} );
ViewData["latLng_List"] = latLngList;
return View();
}
```

> index.cshtml

```
<script> 
@foreach (var item in ViewData["latLng_List"] as IList<>){
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.Lat, item.Lng),
   map: map,
   title: 'Hello World!'
   });
}
</script>
```

- There many ways to do that but i make it relative to your answer.

Comment: So I actually have two separate lists, for latitude and longitude. Would it be a nested @foreach then? Sorry I am still super new to this. Could you please give an example on how to do this?

Comment: @Student04 why would you have two separate list for lat and lng, the best practice is to create one List of (Lat and Lng as object) and pass it to view. but i will edit my answer to give you another option related to your code.